# Solving a nonlinear least-square problem with a nonlinear equality constraint

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, constraints

Given three points $P_k \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $k \in \{0,1,2\}$, and two edges $P_0 P_1$ and $P_1 P_2$ connecting them, I'm trying to get my head around the following (representing a very much simplified version of a more involved problem):

- $P_1$ is moved to a new position $P_1'$
- $P_0$ and $P_2$ should be updated to $P_0'$ and $P_2'$ such that we have $\|P_1' - P_0'\| = \|P_1 - P_0\|$ and $\|P_2' - P_1'\| = \|P_2 - P_1\|$. In other words, the lengths of the edges connecting the three points should not change. This means that $P_0'$ and $P_2'$ can move on circles with respective radii $\|P_1 - P_0\|$ and $\|P_2 - P_1\|$ centred at $P_1'$
- At the same time, $P_0$ and $P_2$ should move as little as possible, i.e. $\|P_0 - P_0'\|$ and $\|P_2 - P_2'\|$ should be minimal

A visualisation of the above might look as follows:

[image]

Now, this problem can be easily solved by hand: $P_0'$ and $P_2'$ must lie on the intersections of the edges $P_0 P_1'$ and $P_1' P_2$ with the circles mentioned above.

However, as the actual setting is more involved (e.g. there might be many more points and connected edges, or even a 2D network of them), I'd like to consider the problem in a (nonlinear) optimisation setting. As such, the first condition can be formulated as a (single) nonlinear equality constraint, i.e.
$$g(P_0', P_1', P_2') = (\|P_1 - P_0\| - \|P_1' - P_0'\|)^2 + (\|P_2 - P_1\| - \|P_2' - P_1'\|)^2 = 0.$$

In other words, the nonlinear equality constraint gives us a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as feasible domain (though we only have two scalar degrees of freedom, the angles of the two edges). Furthermore, the second condition can be formulated as a nonlinear least-squares problem, i.e.
$$\min_{P_0', P_2'} f(P_0', P_2') = \frac12 \Big( \|P_0 - P_0'\|^2 + \|P_2 - P_2'\|^2 \Big).$$

For a general nonlinear least-squares problem *without* (nonlinear) equality constraint, I'd use a Gauss-Newton method to solve it numerically. *With* the constraint present, I'm not certain how to proceed.

[Edit]
One option might be to introduce a Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$ and solve for $\nabla f - \lambda \nabla g = 0$, e.g. using a Newton-Lagrange or constrained Gauss-Newton approach as described in [these lecture notes](https://cdn.syscop.de/publications/Diehl2016.pdf) (Chapter 12). However, I have some doubts about the nonlinear equality constraint $g$ — we actually have an equality constraint for each individual edge (so two of them following the example), which results in multiple (two) Lagrangian multipliers. At the same time, summing these to form a single equality constraint as I did above looks valid (the individual terms are squared, so the only way for the constraint to vanish is for each term to vanish).

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully grasp the problem. The minimization problem seems to live on $S^2 \times S^2$, the Cartesian product of two spheres, which can be covered with one system of four coordinates – say, two latitude-longitude pairs. On this space a function is defined, which depends parametrically on the three displacement parameters of $P_1$. You want to find the minimum of this function on this 4D space. From this point of view the minimization can be done without constraints, although one must check for possible minima at the boundary of the coordinate system. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: For this "little" problem you don't need to solve an optimization problem because the solution is easily obtainable by making $$P_0'=P_2'+\frac{(P_0-P_2')}{|P_0-P_2' |}|P_0-P_2|$$ etc.

Comment: It also seems that you can simply forget either about $P_0$ or $P_2$, focusing on the problem for only one of them at a time. Unless you want to minimize, say, the sum of their displacements, rather than their individual displacements.

Comment: @pglpm Correct for an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$, even easier for the one in my setting, which is in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Furthermore, in this — intentionally very basic — example, minimising individual displacements and minimising the sum of displacements is equivalent. However, for a more involved problem (e.g. with more points/edges), that is no longer the case, in which case I choose to focus on the sum of displacements (as indicated by the objective function $f$).

Comment: @Cesareo Agreed, but as mentioned in the question, the illustrated example is intentionally kept very simple. I also indicated why I want to look into an optimisation-based approach (as the actual setting is more involved). Introducing the problem with a basic example and moving on from there seemed a natural approach to me, but apparently it is somewhat confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

Really, the applied approach can be modified.

Let

- $r_0 = \|P_0P_1\|,\; r_2=\|P_1P_2\|\tag1$
- $P_k\rightarrow b_k\in\mathbb C^3,\;P'_k\rightarrow z_k \in\mathbb C^3,\tag2$
  then
- $z_0(\varphi_0) = z_1 + r_0e^{i\varphi_0},\quad z_2(\varphi_2) = z_1 + r_2e^{i\varphi_2},\tag3$
- $f(\varphi_0,\varphi_2) = \dfrac12(|z_0(\varphi_0)-b_0|^2+|z_2(\varphi_2)-b_2|^2).\tag4$
  $ $

Proposed $2$-parametric model allows to avoid Lagrange multipliers method and looks the easiest for the given problem.